# Manage different versions of a Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sharepoint

How to implement a concept in Web Application where in i have the flow from one of my version say classic to a newer version we have hosted.
For example in gmail(Regular to Html version) or SharePoint(between different versions)
And also what key points to take care while doing the same.

Answer (score -1):

To implement different web application version, same as having multiple application.
Now, in this case three major factors works.

- Source Control and its versioning
- Sharing session between two applications
- Either share same database or make a copy of another database

Lets focus more on Session sharing.One way is to implement Single Sign On method.
Second one is to having a session manager at single point (SQL- memcached - redis).